# Change color text in select html

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a dropdown menu for country selections. The color on the screen needs to be white but now the dropdown selection is also white with a white background. Is there a way to change that?

CSS:

```
.styled-select select {
    background: url('images/dob-field-bg2.png') no-repeat;
    outline: none;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 20px bold helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <select name="Country">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Change the `color : #fff` to  `color:#333;` its enough ..

Answer (score 1):

Try to add like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EH2H3/)**

**CSS:**

```
select option{
    color:#333;
}
```

You can add background-color for options like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EH2H3/2/)**

**CSS with background-color for dropdown:**

```
select option {
    color:#333;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `color: #fff` to `color: #000`